# Do all valid emails contain at least one @ symbol?

Tags: javascript, validation, email

I'm not trying to come up with full email validation. I'm trying to prevent a specific problem:

I've had users use the contact form on my website, which asks for "`Name`", "`Email`" and "`Message`", and just by hilarious mistake, I get the info, "`First Name`", "`Last Name`", "`Message`", and I think to myself, 'Shit where did I leave my Yellow Pages?'

So, I don't want to validate email, I just want to remind people that it's not last name we're asking for it's email.

I'm thinking I check for an `@` symbol, and I want to make sure I'm not neglecting valid emails.

Are there valid emails with no `@` symbols in them?

Comment: @SteveMitcham, nope, my question isn't about validation, it's about preventing a specific user error.

Comment: I cleared the duplicate comment, but that page had some of the information that is in the answers below.

Comment: I have a cousin in South Africa called `Jurgen MBeki@`, you insensitive clod :-)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I had read through a bunch of other questions before posting my own. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @paxdiablo He'd be just fine. As long as his email also had an @ symbol : )

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per RFC5322:

> An addr-spec is a specific Internet identifier that contains a locally interpreted string followed by the at-sign character ("@", ASCII value 64) followed by an Internet domain.

So, yes, all email addresses must have the `@` character.

Prior to the internet taking over the world, it *was* possible for email addresses to have other formats, like the FidoNet mail address `1:170/918.10`, user number 10 at FidoNet node `1:170/918`.

But given the ratio of internet users to FidoNet users currently stands at about a gazillion or more to one, that's for historical interest only.

Comment: This helps a lot, but do all emails also need a "."  or a ".co" etc 

I’m also trying to do this, but I’m stuck at this "." question

Comment: @TahaParacha: from RFC5322: "A liberal syntax for the domain portion of addr-spec is given here.  However, the domain portion contains addressing information specified by and used in other protocols (e.g., RFC1034, RFC1035, RFC1123, RFC5321).  It is therefore incumbent upon implementations to conform to the syntax of addresses *for the context* in which they are used." That means context-dependent so you need to adjust based on what it's being used for.

Comment: @TahaParacha: for example, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034 states a preferred name syntax where the `.` is not needed, `river-styx` is an acceptable domain name. However, if you try to send *mail* to `paxdiablo@river-styx`, I'll never see it :-) That's why email confirmation processes are useful (sending an email with a confirmation link or required action).

Answer (score 4):

As defined in RFC5322, section 3.4.1:

> An addr-spec is a specific Internet identifier that contains a
> locally interpreted string followed by the at-sign character ("@",
> ASCII value 64) followed by an Internet domain.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322

Answer (score 1):

All valid email addresses contain the @ symbol. You can read the Internet Message Format standard for more information: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322

Specifically 3.4.1. Addr-spec specification: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, per [**RFC5322**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322), every email address must have one at-sign, given the basic format of `local-name@domain.com`...

> An addr-spec is a specific Internet identifier that contains a locally interpreted string followed by the at-sign character ("@", ASCII value 64) followed by an Internet domain.

But make sure not to validate for *only one at-sign*, because it's possible for an e-mail address to have several.  After all, there are other RFCs!

[**RFC2822**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-10) gave us the ability to use quoted-strings in e-mail addresses...

> **3.2.2. Quoted characters**
>
> Some characters are reserved for special interpretation, such as
> delimiting lexical tokens.  To permit use of these characters as
> uninterpreted data, a quoting mechanism is provided.
>
> quoted-pair     =       ("" text) / obs-qp

So `"@"@gmail.com` is a valid email address.

Don't forget about [**RFC5321**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321), either!  This defines another basic procedure for having as many `@` signs as you want in your email address...

> Note that the backslash, "\", is a quote character, which is used to
> indicate that the next character is to be used literally (instead of
> its normal interpretation).  For example, "Joe\,Smith" indicates a
> single nine-character user name string with the comma being the
> fourth character of that string.

So, then, `\@@gmail.com` is also a technically-valid email address.

Answer (score 0):

Today, yes (see other answers); but the historic answer is: no.

The original standard (RFC822 ff) made it possible to have extremely short, valid and working email addresses like "i.me". (DDJ once ran a contest.)
An @ was just indicating the postbox within a host; so if you owned the entire host (like, your own server or PC), then you didn't need an @.

The rules for checking email addresses were and are complicated. In an effort to simplify them somewhat, and match the bad practice of many broken "checkers", the - originally invalid - assumption an email address would contain an @ was eventually incorporated into the official standard.